# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement `UICollectionView` in Swift.

I have a problem regarding to optional value in line `let array = objects.objectForKey("image_url") as [String]`

I don't know what's wrong on this my code.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

var data: [String] = [] ;

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var collectionView: UICollectionView

    let json = "https://api.photozou.jp/rest/search_public.json?keyword=bike"//"http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7817937/nameko.json"
    let uri = NSURL(string: json)
    let uridata = NSData(contentsOfURL: uri)
    let objects = uridata.objectFromJSONData() as NSDictionary
    let array = objects.objectForKey("image_url") as [String]
    data += array

    //println(array)



}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
    let url = NSURL(string: data[indexPath.row])
    cell.image.setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil)

    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Does anyone have solution about this error?

Comment: Have you verified the received JSON data? Is objects not nil? Is objects.objectForKey("image_url") an array of strings?

Comment: Yes, object is not nil and String.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the crash like this:

```
 if objects != nil  
{
   if objects.objectForKey("image_url") != nil
   {
      let array = objects.objectForKey("image_url") as [String]
       data += array
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that: 1. the first `if` is redundant, because there's an explicit cast to `NSDictionary` (exception if nil or not a dictionary); 2. it doesn't handle the case where the value for that key is not an array of strings

Comment: @Antonio thanks for the comment. I'm not really good in Swift. but I know for sure that this code will make the crash go away

Comment: No it doesn't - if `objects["image_url"]` is not an array of strings, it generates a runtime exception

Comment: @Antonio yes, you're right, but I was meaning "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" crash

Comment: To be more precise, the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` can be replaced by another runtime error

Comment: Ok - we got to the same conclusion. However I suggest you to make that explicit in your answer, for clarity

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
let array = objects.objectForKey("image_url") as [String]
```

A dictionary always returns an optional, which can be `nil`, but you are also doing a forced cast to an array of `String`. The error can be caused by either:

- the dictionary having no value with `image_url` key (`objectForKey` returns `nil`)
- the dictionary has a value for that key, but it's not a `Array<String>`

I would change that line (and the next) to this:

```
let array = objects.objectForKey("image_url") as? [String]
if let array = array {
    data += array
}
```

The first line doesn't crash if either there's no value for the `image_url` key, or its value is **not* an array of string. The optional binding ensures that the `data += array` is executed only if `array` is not `nil` (and it also unwraps the array from the optional variable)